# Java Error 26011 - Unpacking RT Failed

Tags: java, vps

im trying to install Java on my windows 2003 VPS, it keeps coming up with the error "26077 - Unpacking RT Failed", i have 9.50GB left so its not a space problem.

Any ideas?

Lewis

Comment: i think you made a typo, thats error 26011 and description states 26077.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old bug log archived at Sun which says something about an conflict with an antivirus program: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6765272